# How to set a view's xml attributes dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, widget, grid-layout

I would like to add a button according to this xml code in a gridLayout.However I can't achive.How can I add a button dynamically(programatically,from sourcecode) according to this xml attributes??GridLayout consist of 10 row and 10 column

Could you help me pls??

`<Button 
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="5"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:text="Can"
/>`

this is screenshot of what I want to achive. I achive this via xml code.

[image]

Comment: You take a button in your xml. Set its visibility to "invisible/gone". & when you want to show it make it "visible". With your required size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that:

```
android:layout_row="2"
android:layout_column="5"
android:layout_rowSpan="3"
```

are properties that you can assign to a button.

Why you don't use a gridView with an adapter and you inflate a layout containing a button for each item? I think this is a better approch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hours and day attributes will come from user accordig to that parameters I have to add a button. Is it efficient way for me?

Comment: I think using an adapter it's always an efficient way because you can reuse the view. Depending on what you are receiving you can than update the content of the grid.

Comment: could you give me an example code if u have enough time? I have never work with GridView

Comment: This is a great example for gridview. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/. Check it out.